# Struts tag inside another tag STRUTS 1.3

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts, struts-1

I've got a problem. I've been searching for the answer on different forums but unfortunatelly I didn't find the answer. I need this because I'm creating a webpage where you can change language so it cannot be hard coded.I need to do sth like this:

```
<html:option value="<bean:message key="region"/>"><bean:write name="region"/></html:option>
```

So I want to have the value in html tag set to the string taken from my messages.properties file.The above solution doesn't work. I'd be really grateful for answer because I spend too much time on this....

Comment: If you are using message properties file, then you have to use 
`bean:message` instead of `bean:write`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, posted wrong code, sorry.(doesn't work still)

Comment: You cannot nest a JSP tag in the attribute of another, similar to how you can't nest an XML tag inside the attribute of another. This is basic JSP syntax. Use JSP EL instead. If for some reason you're on an antiquated container that doesn't allow this, use the rt-expr tags instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code using struts tags

```
<bean:define id="regionId"><bean:message key="region"/></bean:define>
<html:option value="<%=regionId%>"><%=regionId%></html:option>
```

or better using JSTL

```
<fmt:message key="region" var="regionId"/>
<html:option value="${regionId}">${regionId}</html:option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a "more than" symbol who closes nothing.

```
<html:option value="<bean:write name='region'/>">
  <bean:write name="region"/>
</html:option>
```

I suppose you have more than one selection in that select, so your code maybe it should be like this:

```
  <html:select property="Language"> 
      <logic:iterate id="RegionSelection" name="Regionlist" scope="session" type="RegionForm"> 
            <html:option value="<bean:write name='RegionSelection' property='RegionName'/>"> 
                      <bean:write name='RegionSelection' property='RegionName'/> 
            </html:option> 
      </logic:iterate> 
  </html:select>
```

Comment: It's not working. It throws an error: Start tag (<html:option>) not closed properly,  expected '>'.

Comment: You cannot nest a JSP tag in the attribute of another like that; this is basic JSP syntax.